# melonJS unclear on use of "this" and constructor calling

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, melonjs

I'm following this [melon JS tutorial](http://melonjs.github.io/tutorial/), and am on part 3.

I am not clear on a couple things in this code snippet

```
game.PlayerEntity = me.ObjectEntity.extend({

    init: function(x, y, settings) {
        this.parent(x, y, settings);
        ... more code here       
    },
```

Firstly, you're creating a new member in my "game" object called "PlayerEntity" which extends the melonJS (me) Object Entity class. I get that. But I don't understand

1) is the `this` referring to "game" object?

2) If so, then `this.parent` would be referring to the parent of "game"- is this just the ObjectEntity class that it's inheriting from?

3) Why can't I call this from outside `game` object as such? It's saying it has no method `init` even though I've defined one in `game.PlayerEntity {}` object.

```
game.PlayerEntity.init(1, 2, 3);
```

4) if you're calling the constructor with `this.parent(x, y, settings)`, where are `x, y, settings` parameters being set? With Java, you call a constructor as such:

```
public Bicycle(int val1, int val2) {
    myVal1 = val1;
    myVal2 = val2;
}
```

then create new instance of class:

```
Bicycle bike = new Bicycle(1, 2);
```

Therefore the constructor of Bicycle is being called when you create the instance.

But with this, It's not clear to me how `this.parent(x, y, settings);` is "calling the constructor".

Thanks!

Comment: I think this refers to the PlayerEntity and this.parent refers to the ObjectEntity.

Answer (score 1):

This convention was originally described by John Resig. In fact, it even mentions him in the melonJS documentation.

The inheritance taking place is where the `.parent` derivation is coming in to play. Basically  what is happening is `this` is referring to your current object, `PlayerEntity` in this case.

extend is not a built in function and does do some things behind the scenes - one of which is to modify the property `.parent` to refer to the "super class".  You can see this in the source code

```
Object.extend = function(prop) {
    // _super rename to parent to ease code reading
    var parent = this.prototype;
```

Since `PlayerEntity` essentially extended `ObjectEntity`, what is happening during this call

```
this.parent(x, y, settings);
```

is that `ObjectEntity` is being called with those 3 parameters (x,y,settings) to construct the underlying properties and state using inheritance.

melonJS source code on github: https://github.com/melonjs/melonJS/blob/master/src/core.js

Comment: Awesome! thanks. Few more questions. 1) Where are `x, y, settings` params being defined though? 2)To preserve inheritance, can't I just use `ObjectEntity.apply(this, arguments);` within PlayerEntity? 3) How is `init` called? I didn't find `init` as a member of ObjectEntity class  here http://melonjs.github.io/docs/me.ObjectEntity.html